# Eclipse ADT produces infinite error messages in logcat when running on device

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I received the following message when I tried to debug on my android device after it failed to run. I got a message in console saying the APK was invalid, and to check the logcat for more information. Below was the logcat output and it just kept going.  I noticed the Android version on my device and the version on my project were different. So I right-clicked the  Android file(the project was set up with libgdx), Properties -> Android -> checked box with same Android version as my device. It fixed the problem.

I'm new to Android and I would like to know what the message means and why it doesn't stop.

```
 03-22 23:30:01.510: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:01.510: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
    03-22 23:30:11.570: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:11.570: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
    03-22 23:30:19.908: E/Watchdog(2024): !@Sync 108
    03-22 23:30:21.600: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:21.600: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
    03-22 23:30:31.620: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:31.620: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
    03-22 23:30:41.669: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:41.669: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
    03-22 23:30:45.023: E/WifiHW(2024): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
    03-22 23:30:45.854: E/WifiHW(2024): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
    03-22 23:30:49.908: E/Watchdog(2024): !@Sync 109
    03-22 23:30:51.769: E/MtpService(6009): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    03-22 23:30:51.769: E/MtpService(6009): battPlugged Type : 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The logcat you posted does not just belong to your application, the log you posted shows services and other applications that are running on the device, so what you have posted has nothing to do with your application.

Here is what the [logcat documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) says:

> logcat
>
> The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and
>   viewing system debug output. Logs from various applications and
>   portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers,
>   which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command. You can
>   use logcat from an ADB shell to view the log messages.
>
> For complete information about logcat options and filtering
>   specifications, see [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).
>
> For more information on accessing logcat from DDMS, instead of the
>   command line, see [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).